# Is it possible to instruct ServicePartitionClient to talk to a specific node in service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have

```
public class HttpCommunicationClient : HttpClient, ICommunicationClient
{
    public HttpCommunicationClient()
        : base(new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false, UseCookies = false })
    {
    }

    public HttpCommunicationClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
        : base(handler)
    {
    }

    public HttpCommunicationClient(HttpMessageHandler handler, bool disposeHandler)
        : base(handler, disposeHandler)
    {
    }

    #region ICommunicationClient

    string ICommunicationClient.ListenerName { get; set; }

    ResolvedServiceEndpoint ICommunicationClient.Endpoint { get; set; }

    ResolvedServicePartition ICommunicationClient.ResolvedServicePartition { get; set; }

    #endregion ICommunicationClient
}
```

and

```
public class HttpCommunicationClientFactory : CommunicationClientFactoryBase<HttpCommunicationClient>
{
    private readonly Func<HttpCommunicationClient> _innerDispatcherProvider;

    public HttpCommunicationClientFactory(IServicePartitionResolver servicePartitionResolver = null, IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler> exceptionHandlers = null, string traceId = null)
        : this(() => new HttpCommunicationClient(), servicePartitionResolver, exceptionHandlers, traceId)
    {
    }

    public HttpCommunicationClientFactory(Func<HttpCommunicationClient> innerDispatcherProvider, IServicePartitionResolver servicePartitionResolver = null, IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler> exceptionHandlers = null, string traceId = null)
        : base(servicePartitionResolver, exceptionHandlers, traceId)
    {
        if (innerDispatcherProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerDispatcherProvider));
        }

        _innerDispatcherProvider = innerDispatcherProvider;
    }

    protected override void AbortClient(HttpCommunicationClient dispatcher)
    {
        if (dispatcher != null)
        {
            dispatcher.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected override Task<HttpCommunicationClient> CreateClientAsync(string endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dispatcher = _innerDispatcherProvider.Invoke();
        dispatcher.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint, UriKind.Absolute);

        return Task.FromResult(dispatcher);
    }

    protected override bool ValidateClient(HttpCommunicationClient dispatcher)
    {
        return dispatcher != null && dispatcher.BaseAddress != null;
    }

    protected override bool ValidateClient(string endpoint, HttpCommunicationClient dispatcher)
    {
        return dispatcher != null && dispatcher.BaseAddress == new Uri(endpoint, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
}
```

and is using it like below

```
var servicePartitionClient = new ServicePartitionClient<HttpCommunicationClient>(_httpClientFactory,
                                                                                           _options.ServiceUri,
                                                                                           _options.GetServicePartitionKey?.Invoke(context),
                                                                                           _options.TargetReplicaSelector,
                                                                                           _options.ListenerName,
                                                                                           _options.OperationRetrySettings);

using (var responseMessage = await servicePartitionClient.InvokeWithRetryAsync(httpClient => ExecuteServiceCallAsync(httpClient, context)))
{
    await responseMessage.CopyToCurrentContext(context);
}
```

The question is now, if I know at the time of using ServicePartitionClient that I would like it to connect to a specific node, is there any way to do so?

The case is that its a gateway application that forward requests to other services and I would like it to behave like with sticky sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense to think in terms of services than nodes. So rather than connecting to a specific node, you're actually connecting to a specific instance of a service.

When you're connecting to a service, if it's stateless, it shouldn't matter which instance you connect to, by definition of it being stateless. If you find that a user is tied to a specific instance of a service, that service is stateful (it's keeping track of some user state), and that's exactly the type of scenario that **stateful services** are meant to handle.

Comment: There are corner cases. Signalr needs in the handshaking to do 3 requests that must hit the same instance (yes its not stateless). Two solutions exists, either sticky sessions on loadbalancer or (for my case when writing a reverse proxy, i can implement stick session myself using a cookie). But technically, yes you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, where I in the `ExecuteServiceCallAsync` call below reads a cookie from request with the information about which node it was connected to if its a sticky session, and if no cookie is present i set one with the information from the request. If the node dont exist any more the cookie is updated to new node.

```
using (var responseMessage = await servicePartitionClient.InvokeWithRetryAsync(httpClient => ExecuteServiceCallAsync(httpClient, context)))
{
    await responseMessage.CopyToCurrentContext(context);
}
```